# Ram suggestion for dual channel Thinkpad X1 extreme gen 1?

Tags: memory

I have a gen 1 Thinkpad X1 Extreme. I just realized I've been running it with a single stick of 32 gb ram the whole time, which I guess means it may be missing out on some dual channel mode performance gains. Question: can I just buy any 32gb stick of notebook ram and shove it in there, or do I need to pay attention to type/brand/speed etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If the type and speed is the same and you have a second ram slot, you can mostly mix and match memory.

Comment: What do you mean by type in this case?

Comment: DDR3, DDR4, DDR5, SODIMM and DIMM

Comment: You probably need DDR4 SODIMM